# Remove indent in Google Scripts sendEmail()

Tags: google-apps-script

When I use the following function to send an email in Google script, the second line has an indent that I don't want.

Here's the function:

```
    function AppealsListContact() {

const recipients = 'ksparks@eastern.edu' //,cde@xyz.com'
const sub = 'Pending UEPCC Appeals'
const line1 = 'Dear EU Colleague:'
const line2 = ''
const line3 = 'You have items waiting for you attention in the appeals process. Please attend to these as soon as possible.'

const body = `${line1}
              ${line2}
              ${line3}`

MailApp.sendEmail(recipients,sub,body)

}
```

And here's the resulting email:

```
"Dear EU Colleague:

               You have items waiting for you attention in the appeals 
process. Please attend to these as soon as possible."
```

Why is there an indent space before the message ("You have items"), and how can I remove it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Remove Indent

```
function AppealsListContact() {

  const recipients = 'jimesteban@jimesteban.com';
  const sub = 'Pending UEPCC Appeals';
  const line1 = 'Dear EU Colleague:';
  const line2 = ''
  const line3 = 'You have items waiting for you attention in the appeals process. Please attend to these as soon as possible.';

  const body = `${line1}\n${line2}${line3}`;

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, sub, body)

}
```